# Android Mp Android Chart Custom Design

Tags: android, kotlin, charts, mpandroidchart

I want to create a line chart using [Mp Chart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

What I want to achieve is this image [image]

But I have got this so far.[image]

the code i am using is this

```
  private fun setData() {
    val entries: MutableList<Entry> = ArrayList()
    entries.add(Entry(0f, 4f))
    entries.add(Entry(1f, 3f))
    entries.add(Entry(2f, 2f))
    entries.add(Entry(3f, 1f))
    entries.add(Entry(4f, 5f))
    entries.add(Entry(5f, 4f))
    entries.add(Entry(6f, 6f))

    val dataSet = LineDataSet(entries, "Customized values")
    dataSet.color = ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.colorPrimary)
    dataSet.valueTextColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context!!, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)

    //****
    // Controlling X axis
    val xAxis = line_chart.xAxis
    // Set the xAxis position to bottom. Default is top
    xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
    //Customizing x axis value
    val months = arrayOf("M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S")

    val formatter = IAxisValueFormatter { value, axis -> months[value.toInt()] }
    xAxis.granularity = 1f // minimum axis-step (interval) is 1
    xAxis.valueFormatter = formatter

    //***
    // Controlling right side of y axis
    val yAxisRight = line_chart.axisRight
    yAxisRight.isEnabled = false

    //***
    // Controlling left side of y axis
    val yAxisLeft = line_chart.axisLeft
    yAxisLeft.granularity = 1f

    // Setting Data
    val data = LineData(dataSet)
    line_chart.data = data
    line_chart.invalidate()
}
```

The xml file is simple Mp android xml view

```
<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/line_chart"/>
```

Kindly Help me to achieve the above image line chart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the gradient effect,

```
dataSet.drawFilled = true
dataSet.filledDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.gradient)
```

And `gradient.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:startColor="#00cfcce3"
        android:endColor="#ffcfcce3" />
</shape>
```